# Import Angular module from npm package

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, package

I want to use `detect-mobile` package (https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/tree/v1.4.4) in `Angular` application.

But it can't be imported usual way. I've tried each of following:

```
import { MobileDetect } from 'mobile-detect';
import MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect';
import {}  from 'mobile-detect';
```

Mobile detect `d.ts` file has following structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how should it be imported? Also I would be greatly appreciated for explanation how such package differs from others.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qptjt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used for the export - `export = MobileDetect` - means that the package was written use CommonJS style exports. See [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7185#issuecomment-354566288) for further explanation.

Therefore the way to import this is:

```
import * as MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect'
```

Also, I believe if you are using the `esModuleInterop` TypeScript compiler flag, you can just write:

```
import MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect'
```

Comment: but what the difference with jasmine-theories for example? It contains : `declare var jsminTheories: jasmineTheories.jasmineTheoriesStatic;
 export default jsminTheories;`
and can be imported like: `import theoretically from 'jasmine-theories';` Appreciate if you add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Now I see that `export default jsminTheories` is ES6 module. But could you please add the explanation to the answer